# Angular - add logic before leaving page - does not work with HostListener

Tags: angular

I need to add some logic in angular component before user navigates away from the page.
Trying a few suggestions after googling possible solutions but nothing seems to work for me.
I tried this option (does not work when user leaves the page):

```
@HostListener('window:onbeforeunload', ['$event'])
    unloadHandler() {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('leave?');        
    }
```

Also tried this in html (neither works):

```
<div (window:onbeforeunload)="unloadHandler()"></div>
```

Could someone advice something?

Comment: try to use `ngOnDestroy(){}`

Comment: What about `onDestroy`? Or `CanDeactivate` guard? These two won't stop user from closing browser, but will activate when you change page in your app.

Comment: ngDestroy does not help. CanDeactivate - didn't try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should return value there and correct syntax, that's result you want:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    unloadHandler() {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('leave?');        

        return false;
    }
```